# Phone gap social sharing plugin Customization?

Tags: android, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app

I have implemented the social sharing plugin by the following [link](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin)

its working perfect ,but i want to customize the plugin like when user clicks on the share app tab then  only following option need to display email,watts-app, sms, Facebook non other option should not display to the user, but now its displaying  all the social media apps to the user to share the specific link or text ,so please suggest to me how to solve this one

Comment: Have you tried Cutomizing it's java file ?

Comment: yes i commented the some functions code which is related to the other social apps like shareViaTwitter,shareViaInstagram in socialsharing.java file but still same thing happening

Comment: Also do same thing in js also.

Comment: ya i have done same changes in socialsharing.js file still same thing is happening no luck  @jaydroider